# Using undefined time in a crontab job

Tags: crontab

What happens if you program a crontab job like this:

```
* * * * * the command
```

Will it be executed every minute, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be executed every minute of every hour of every day of every month.

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
# ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
# │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```